# What is wrong with my unit test code for this MVC project? I keep getting 'does not contain definition' and 'no extension method error'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

(EDIT** I was able to get the code to compile and execute a unit test that passed. In addition to the code fixes, there was a problem with VS2010 running the unit test indefinitely. I had to replace a dll file that was changed during an aborted install of vs 2012. I posted the changes to the controller and unit test at the bottom of the page. Thanks to all who posted answers.)

This is the first question I've ever asked online about coding. I've been learning C# .NET and other associated stuff using free tutorials for about a year now. So far I've been able to research and troubleshoot everything on my own. I'm starting to venture into uncharted territory now and I can't seem to find an answer.

I have been working on a tutorial called "Learn MVC Model View Controller Step by Step in 7 days". Here is the link:
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259560/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in-7

I have researched the suggested links for the error:

```
Error 'Mvccustomer.Models.Customer' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayCustomer'        and no extension method 'DisplayCustomer' accepting a first argument of type     'Mvccustomer.Models.Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an     assembly reference?)
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to find a similar situation where someone is creating a unit test with a similar file reference. Mind you, I'm totally new to MVC and unit testing.

One problem with the tutorial is that that in the videos the author uses one set of namespaces/file names and another in the written tutorial.  I was able to troubleshoot that problem on my own. For instance, in the beginning, he uses 'Mvccustomer' as a project name but by the 4th or 5th lab on the first day he's calling it 'Mvcinputscreen'. 
I susspect that the trouble lies in how the customer class is referenced in the project but I can't figure it out so far.

Here is the unit test that gives me an error:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Mvccustomer.Models;

namespace MvcUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer();
            var varresult = obj.DisplayCustomer();
            Assert.AreEqual("DisplayCustomer", varresult.ViewName);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the customer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Mvccustomer.Models;

namespace Mvccustomer.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string CustomerCode { set; get; }
        public double Amount { set; get; }
    }
}
```

This is the Display Customer View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Mvccustomer.Models.Customer>"     %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    The customer id is <%= Model.Id %> <br />

    The customer id is <%= Model.CustomerCode %> <br />

    <%if (Model.Amount > 100)
      {%>
    This is a priveleged customer.
    <% }
      else
      { %>
    This is a normal customer
    <%} %>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the customer controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mvccustomer.Models;


namespace Mvccustomer.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Customer/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult FillCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
    {
        return View(obj);
    }

}
```

}

Let me know if I need to post any more elements of the project. When I build the Mvccustomer project it compiles fine with no errors. It's only the unit test that is giving me trouble. I imagine that this question is a bit convoluted and I eagerly await the learning experience that will come with all of the constructive criticism. Thank you.

Edited Controller and Unit Test that ultimately worked:

Customer Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mvccustomer.Models;
using Mvccustomer.Controllers;

namespace Mvccustomer.Controllers
{
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Customer/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult FillCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayCustomerView(CustomerModel customerModel)
    {
      var myView = View("DisplayCustomerView", customerModel);
      //myView.ViewName = "DisplayCustomer";
      return myView;
    }

}
}
```

Edited Unit Test:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Mvccustomer.Models;
using Mvccustomer.Controllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcUnitTest
{


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DisplayCustomer()
    {
      // instantiates new instance of CustomerController class
      CustomerController controller = new CustomerController();

      var customer = new CustomerModel();

      var customerViewActionResult = controller.DisplayCustomerView(customer);
      var customerViewViewResult = customerViewActionResult as ViewResult;


      Assert.AreEqual("DisplayCustomerView", customerViewViewResult.ViewName);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be CustomerController obj = new CustomerController(); ?

Answer (score 6):

You are calling a method `obj.DisplayCustomer()` in a `Customer` object in the test. However, I don't see any `DisplayCustomer` method in `Customer`.

The `CustomerController` class has a method `DisplayCustomer` but this one requires one parameter of type `Customer`.

```
CustomerController obj = new CustomerController();
var varresult = obj.DisplayCustomer(new Customer());
```

---

If intellisense does not show the method, it's probably because the method does not exist or is private.

Comment: Oliver, Thank you for your reply. The above code snippet seems to work but the 'Assert.AreEqual....' statement keeps returning an error concerning the 'ViewName'saying:  System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult does not contain a defintiion for Viewname and no extension method 'ViewName' accepting a first argument of type System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)  Thanks again!

Comment: The class `ViewResultBase` that derives from `ActionResult` declares a property `ViewName`. If `DisplayCustomer` returns a `ViewResultBase` (or a derived class like `PartialViewResult` or `ViewResult`) you can cast this result to one of these classes. `((ViewResultBase)varresult).ViewName`. Set a breakpoint on the `Assert.AreEqual` line and hover with the mouse over `varresult`. A tooltip will show you the real type of `varresult`. See also [ViewResultBase Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase(v=vs.98).aspx)

Comment: The above comment led to the solution....I and to add the using statement and cast the action result at as a ViewResult....I think that's right. Ultimately, the tutorial was garbage and I'm moving on to better code snippets and intelligible videos...I'm going to go back and comment the hell out of what I made for practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
CustomerController obj = new CustomerController();
var result = obj.DisplayCustomer(new Customer()) **as ViewResult**;
Assert.AreEqual("Expected", result.ViewName);
```

Comment: Tyler, Thank you kindly for your help with this! I tried th e above code snippet and put "DisplayCustomer" in for "expected"...is that right? I keep getting an error under 'ViewName' saying System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult does not contain a defintiion for Viewname and no extension method 'ViewName' accepting a first argument of type System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: no I just put 'expected' in as an example, its whatever name you expect your view to return! Did you include the 'as ViewResult' part of code? It is needed to cast your var to a ViewResult, which definitely contains a definition for ViewName!

Comment: highlighted the 'as ViewResult' bit

Comment: I did, there is an error: 'the type ViewResult could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)' Seems like I'm getting closer though...

Comment: ViewResult is from the System.Web.Mvc namespace. Try right-clicking on the error and you should see an option of resolve. If that's not there then ensure that System.Web.Mvc is added as a reference to your project

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for the view name that is supposed to be returned by the controller, but you didn't create a controller. Instead you are calling `.DisplayCustomer()` on the `Customer` not the `CustomerController`

I would also make your code a little more explanatory. Names of unit test functions should explain what they are testing. Variable names should explain what they are (`obj` is a bad name, because it is meaningless).

Consider reading another programmer's code and needing to understand how it works, or coming back to your own code 2 years from now and trying to remember how it worked. Giving things explanatory names helps. I would rewrite your test like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DisplayCustomer_ReturnsViewNamed_DisplayCustomer()
    {
        const string expectedViewName = "DisplayCustomer";
        var customer = new Customer();
        var controllerUnderTest = new CustomerController();

        var result = controllerUnderTest.DisplayCustomer(customer);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedViewName, result.ViewName);
    }
```

If you like reading through programming books, I highly recommend [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert Martin. It is written with code examples in Java, but Java is syntactically close to C#, and it is a great book on keeping your code readable, simple and well organized. I keep a [cheat-sheet of notes from the book](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/clean-code-cheat-sheet/) that I ofter refer to when coding.

---

*Edit:*

Regarding your new error:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' does not contain a definition for
>   'ViewName' and no extension method 'ViewName' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The method signature on your controller is:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
```

It returns an `ActionResult` object. The property `.ViewName` does not exist on this type, it is actually a property of `ViewResult`.

The line inside the `DisplayCustomer()` method in the controller returns:

```
return View(obj);
```

The `View()` method actually returns a `ViewResult`, but the `ViewResult` class extends `ActionResult`:

```
public class ViewResult : ActionResult
```

So it is OK that your method signature is set to `ActionResult` but you actually always return a `ViewResult` since `ViewResult` *is* an `ActionResult`. (Typical OO inheritance stuff, but hopefully this part makes sense so far).

In your test, when you call `DisplayCustomer()` as far as the test knows all it has to go by is the method signature, which is tellign the compiler that it will return an `ActionResult`.  Therefore the compiler is trying to find a property names `ViewName` on the `Actionresult` class which does not exist.

There are 2 ways you can fix this:

One is to simply cast the result in your test:

```
var varresult = (ViewResult)obj.DisplayCustomer();
```

Or, since that method always returns a `ViewResult` you can change the method signature to indicate that it returns this more specific type:

```
public ViewResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
{
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: CodingWithSpike, Thank you for your reply. I have been at this for hours now. I've tried all the different code snippets in the answers here...  It seems as though the corrections as it pertains to calling the CustomerController fixed a lot of problems. However, there is a new error: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'ViewName' and no extension method 'ViewName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\MVC Projects\Mvccustomer\UnitTest1\UnitTest1.cs

Comment: I was able to build a functioning application using this tutorial but the unit testing tutorial has no video and the code snippets seem to be messed up somehow. I guess I just need to understand how the unit test is constructed. Where does ViewName come into play? Should it be referenced somewhere else in the code?

Comment: The above View Result fix was what finally did the trick! I had to enlist some help last night to have it explained to me. I'll probably be staring at the new code for days before I finally digest it. When I get off work tonight, I will post all the new code and the other fixes that were required.  Thank you to all who posted answers here! Awesome...

Comment: Glad we could all help. Please be sure to up-vote and/or mark as accepted the answers and comments that helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to boil this down to not using a [mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing) framework for simplicity, which would have eliminated or reduced the need for the `try/catch` (depending on your own preferences/style).

Just noticed one of the reasons you were having issues, the method `DisplayCustomer()` is supposed to return `ViewResult` not `ActionResult`.

However the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259560/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in-7#Step%204:-%20Write%20the%20unit%20test) still doesn't work, as getting the view name doesn't happen until `ExecuteResult()` is called.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void DisplayCustomerTest_FindsCorrectViewName()
    {
        var expected = "DisplayCustomer";

        var obj = new CustomerController();
        var cContext = new ControllerContext();

        cContext.RouteData.Values.Add("action", expected);
        cContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Customer");

        var actionResult = obj.DisplayCustomer(new Customer());

        //not necessary but helpful
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(ViewResult));

        //down cast
        var vResult = actionResult as ViewResult;

        try // the view name is populated early, and we don't care about what else it does
        {
            vResult.ExecuteResult(cContext);
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException) {} //catch the most specific error type you can

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, vResult.ViewName);

    }
```

for more interesting ways to do this, or more advanced (matter of opinion, and appears to be missing any answer utilizing a proper mocking framework)

[Get View Name where ViewResult.ViewName is empty string for Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301797/get-view-name-where-viewresult-viewname-is-empty-string-for-unit-testing?rq=1)

[down cast explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428725/can-you-explain-liskov-substitution-principle-with-a-good-c-sharp-example)

pardon the styling, no Resharper or StyleCop installed at home.

for unit testing naming conventions consider [Unit test naming best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718464/unit-testing-my-controller-method-results-in-an-empty-viewname