# Route to the view from the OnException method in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to reroute the application to the same view when an Exception is thrown in the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult Action(ModelClass modelObject)
{
    _facade.update(modelObject);
    return new EmptyResult();
}


protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is MyException)
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/ViewFolder/View.cshtml",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };


        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The view name needs to match the name of an `Action` on a controller.

Comment: In which context? Generally it does not need to

Answer (score 0):

The view name is mapped by convention. You don't need to put the full path.

> The ViewName of the result will have the view name that was explicitly
>   passed in to the result. At runtime if the view name isn't specified
>   then ASP.NET MVC will use the "action" value as specified by the
>   routing system. There is no way for it to "guess" in the unit test
>   what the view name should be.
>
> You can find out more information on this post on StackOverflow.com:
>   [Unit testing my controller method results in an empty ViewName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718464/unit-testing-my-controller-method-results-in-an-empty-viewname)

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is MyException)
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = actionName,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };    

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```